# Selecting elements form a structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am representing polynomials p and q as a structure array in the form:

```
p=struct('exponent',{2,3},'coeff',{1,1})
q=struct('exponent',{1,5,6,7},'coeff',{1,1,1,1})
```

I need to be able to select all the exponent elements of q for use in a function. I have attempted to do this by 
    a=q(1,(:)).exponent

I want a to become the array [1,5,6,7]. Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
a = [q.exponent];
```

Accessing a field of a struct *array* like that returns a [list](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the values for each element in the array, which you can just catch in a concatenation operator.